# Programatic content script injection returning same string after url change

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

**Goal:** Re-inject content script after a URL change and grab new name from the DOM

**Problem:** The same variable `name` returns after URL change. The idea is a new URL signifies a new name in the DOM that I would like to populate within my `popup.html`.

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            files: ['contentScript.js']
        });
    }
});
```

**contentScript.js** - Should run after URL change

```
let name;

setTimeout(() => {
  const recordNameEl = document.querySelectorAll('.recordId');
  const recordNameString = recordNameEl[1].textContent;
  const nameArray = recordNameString.split(' ');
  name = nameArray[0];

  // Set name in localStorage. Should reset to new name after URL change
  chrome.storage.local.set({ name });

  // Logs same name after URL changes. Console is defo reloading after each change
  console.log(name);
}, 10000);
```

Surely a new context is created after each script execution triggered by URL change? Not sure why I am getting the same string even after URL change which triggers a console reload

**In case your wondering**

- I'm using `setTimeout()` because the page takes so long to load. If I didn't then I'd get a reference error

Comment: Since the name is printed, the script indeed runs again, so your selector is wrong or the page doesn't change this element or your timeout is too short. Debug it. Also try using  MutationObserver instead of setTimeout.

Comment: I want to check if a string has changed. So not sure if `MutationObserver` will be best... It only checks attribute, childlist changes

Comment: You're checking textContent which is one of the things MutationObserver detects.